# Embedded HTML5 games

Tags: html, mobile

I want to make an html5 website that will allow others to play mobile games directly from the website, without downloading - embedded games.
I tried to search it, but couldn't find any information.
Is there any specific technical term for that?

Comment: Games of what type? Flash? Java Applets? Canvas? Magical Unicorn? What?? Each embedding method has a different way of accomplishing it.

Comment: html5 games. Anyways, I already found the soluion

Comment: If so, please post the correct answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be very easy.
I simply had to use the `iframe` tag.

Here is a working example:

```
<iframe src="//static1.scirra.net/arcade/games/12/play" width="640" height="640" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to embed Java games, they would have to be applets. Then you can use the `<object>` tag.

**[Read all about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html)**